# Primefaces datePicker range filter end date issue

Tags: javascript, jsf, primefaces, datepicker

I am using primefaces 10 dataTable

and I am tring to filter on `java.util.date` column as follows:

```
<p:column field="dateCreated" headerText="Request Date" filterMatchMode="range">
    <f:facet name="filter">
        <p:datePicker widgetVar="dateFilterWidget" pattern="yyyy/MM/dd"  selectionMode="range" onchange="dateFilterChange();">
          <f:convertDateTime type="date"  dateStyle="short" pattern="yyyy/MM/dd" />
        </p:datePicker>                             
    </f:facet>
    <h:outputText value="#{requestItem.dateCreated}">
        <f:convertDateTime pattern="yyyy/MM/dd hh:mm aa" locale="ar"/>
    </h:outputText>
</p:column>
```

**ISSUE :** the filter works as **date >= startDate and date < endDate**

and i want it to work like : **date >= startDate and date <= endDate**

Example : i have request create on 1 October and request created on 7 october
if i choose the range from :

**2021/10/01 - 2021/10/07** the request from **2021/10/07** does not appear in filter result

so i tried to hack the code as follows:

```
function dateFilterChange(){
             var datePicker = PF('dateFilterWidget');
             console.log(datePicker.getDate());
             if(datePicker.getDate() &amp;&amp; datePicker.getDate().length == 2 &amp;&amp; datePicker.getDate()[1]!= null){            
                 var endDate = datePicker.getDate()[1];
                 endDate.setHours(23, 59, 59);
                 console.log('endDate :'+endDate);
             }
             console.log(datePicker.getDate());             
             PF('inboxTableWidget').filter();
         }
```

but still getting same result.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can also opt to take care of this on the server side.

The range filter is handled by [`org.primefaces.model.filter.RangeFilterConstraint`](https://github.com/primefaces/primefaces/blob/10.0.0/src/main/java/org/primefaces/model/filter/RangeFilterConstraint.java). You can overload this class in your project and modify the `isInRange` method to check for `Date`s the way you want to.

Or, if you are using a `LazyDataModel`, simply act on the provided [`org.primefaces.model.FilterMeta`](https://github.com/primefaces/primefaces/blob/10.0.0/src/main/java/org/primefaces/model/FilterMeta.java) of `MatchMode` `RANGE`.